# Chances of memory leak when valgrind says no memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

My `C`  code does not show any memory leak while checking with valgrind. But when i integrate that code with another system, which has its own memory management but of course calls  `malloc`  for allocating memory, shows memory leak. Valgrind check used to be correct everytime, but  this time its not working for me. I would like to know if there is chances of memory leak although `valgrind`  says no memory leak. What can be the strongest parameters of valgrind to set to find the hardest memory leak?

Comment: This is unclear. Could you be more precise.

Comment: @David, thanks for the reply. I have a implemented one data structure in **C** using its standard library. I checked the memory leak using **valgrind** for it.The valgrind shows **no memory leak**. When i integrate the same code with another project, it shows memory leak.The project its own memory management modules but it uses same **malloc** and **free** for allocating memory and freeing it.I always used to do the same before integrating into the project and never got the memory leak after integrating in the project which was tested in the **valgrind** and there was no memory leak.

Comment: contd .... but this time,valgrind does not show any memory leak but there is memory leak once i integrate the same code in the project.

Comment: Sounds like the integration with other project has introduced a memory leak. Why do you not trust valgrind?

Comment: I have been trusting **valgrind** and i just wanted to if there are some rare cases where valgrind also can't detect the memory leak. Can you tell me if there are some options in valgrind that can detect **hardest memory leak**?

Comment: What is hardest memory leak? I see no reason why valgrind would not detect all leaks. Presumably valgrind tells you where the leaked memory was allocated (and hopefully provide call stack). It should be easy enough to debug it from there.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very possible that you still have a memory leak - not because I think that valgrind has bugs, but because I think that integrating it with another project probably exercises the code differently than your test does. (FYI - I haven't found any cases of memory leaks where valgrind says my code is clear, although that's hardly exhaustive proof). I think in order to solve the problem is to either add tests to your un-integrated version or to run the integrated version in valgrind.

Other options might be making sure you're not suppressing any errors that could be harmful, add --leak-check=full, or otherwise play with your valgrind setup.